# Adding a new JSON Object to a file array

Tags: c#, json

I have a JSON file with an array of Objects under "NavigationControls", what I want to do is add a new item to this array and update the file. Can someone please give me some pointers to achieve this please?

```
{
    "LocalId": "section1",
    "Name": "Sample Navigation",
    "Version": "1.0.0.0",
    "NavigationControls": [
        {
            "ControlType": 0,
            "ControlName": "",
            "ControlId": 0,
            "FontSize": 26,
            "Label": "Main Title"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Deserialize.  Add the desired object.  Serialize to file.

Comment: Load and parse the file, add your item to the array, rewrite the file using the new JSON.

Comment: After serialization? Before? Help us understand your actual problem with a complete example that reproduces the problem

Comment: deserialize and feed it to your text and append the new item, or use it as an object and then add the item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can deserialize your data like that, where DBConfig is the object and data the json content

```
    public static DBConfig Carregar()
    { 
        var data = File.ReadAllText("dbconfig.json");

        var config = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DBConfig>(data);

        return config;
    }
```